# Customer login api using Clover SDK

Tags: android, clover-payment

I have create account in clover and using that account i have found the merchantId and created api token for that using these i have created the customer for that merchant.

I have created the customer in clover and using merchantId and API token.Now i want to login with that created customer but i could not find the api for login in clover.can anyone tell me whether the api available for login with customer in clover?

I have referred this link list of clover apis https://www.clover.com/api_docs#!/customers

I created the customer using this api https://www.clover.com/api_docs#!/customers/CreateCustomer

Api url for create customer : https://api.clover.com/v3/merchants/024SK6Q06NKP0/customers

request parameter :

```
{
    "firstName": "Test",
    "lastName": "test Last Name",
    "phoneNumber": "2135124541",
    "emailAddress": "test@gmail.com",
    "zip": "123123",
    "country": "In",
    "city": "Pune",
    "address1": "Vimannagar",
    "state": "Maharashtra"
}
```

It would be great if anyone have idea about this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: great question...